# I make her [cleaning?] the room

Tags: verbs, infinitives

[i] I made her **clean** the room.
[ii] I make her **cleaning** the room.

We use this expression: [somebody do something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1) as [ii]. My asking is can we also use [ii] construction. It seems it can be. Say there’s a situation that my intention of her cleaning is not to clean the room but just to do it for a while, for funny task - you can see a little girl willingly to do the thing just for fun as a recreation; my intention is to do my own work for the while, while she is distracted: e.g: “I made her cleaning the room, while I was reading the letter.”

Comment: You say "It seems it can be".  If you don't mind my asking, how did you come to that conclusion?  Have you seen it used?

Comment: In your link (sense 10 that applies here) I did not see any -ing verbs as in [ii]. Anyway it cannot be said that way.

Comment: @snailplane, that's come out of the later words about the little girl imagination.

Comment: She was "pretending" to clean her room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[i] (I made her clean the room) is correct.  This uses "clean" as a verb, and "her" as the object of the verb "made".

[ii] is incorrect.  Here are two similar, but correct, statements.  Note that their meanings are very different.  They use "cleaning" as a noun, and "her" is not the object of the verb "made":

- I made a big deal about her cleaning the room.
- I made her cleaning the room into the topic of a blog post.